# Adjusting font size

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, fontsize

Currently using a template from my university that uses this to define font:

```
 \def\titlefont{\rmfamily}
```

AND

```
 \setsansfont[
    Path = fonts/,
    Extension = .ttf,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *,
    ItalicFeatures = FakeSlant,
    BoldItalicFont = *-Bold,
    BoldItalicFeatures = FakeSlant
]{Tahoma}
```

AND

```
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

Now, I must admit I am fairly new to working with XeLaTeX, so I have tried to find a solution to make the Tahoma now used one or two sizes smaller, but I could not find it. I have tried using `scale` and `size` and variations of this:

`\newcommand{\bigfont}[1]{%
 \fontspec[Ligatures={Common,Rare}]{Zapfino}%
 \fontsize{30pt}{36pt}\selectfont #1}`

but no actual luck.

Can someone help me out?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a small *compilable* code that we can play with?

Comment: If using a "template" the font sizes are presumably fixed to be standard for all submissions . So first question is why are you needing to change from what the instructions give as perceived "requirements" the most likely location is in the style/classes files but you could try \small \large \Huge

Comment: If the reason you want Tahoma to be slightly bigger or smaller than the other fonts in your document, you want to add the command `\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}` before you load your fonts. If you do this, also add the font feature `Scale=1.0` to `\setmainfont`. It’s a good idea to do this by default.

Comment: If you want to make the font bigger or smaller in one place, you can use commands like `\large`, and if you want to select a specific point size, use `\fontsize`.

Comment: Finally, if you just want all the text in your document to be bigger, you can pass the option `12pt` or `14pt` to your `\documentclass`.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to set a font, let's say Tahoma is this one :

```
\setmainfont[
Scale=1,Ligatures={TeX},
BoldFont={Tahoma Bold}, 
ItalicFont={Tahoma Italic},]{Tahoma}
```

Using that, it doesn't matter if you have serif or sans since it's your main font.

Then you just have to do this in order to have a 5 size factor in your font :

```
\newfontfamily\font5{Tahoma}[Scale=5]
```